# PyQt application screen change notification

Tags: python, pyqt

I checked some information. C++ has an onScreenChanged function to notify us of screen changes, but I tried it and found that PyQt does not have this onScreenChanged function. How should I know that the application has changed the screen display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know if a window has changed screen then you must use the [`screenChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#screenChanged) signal of the associated QWindow(use [`windowHandle()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowHandle) method of QWidget). The QWindow is created after calling the show method:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    w.show()
    w.windowHandle().screenChanged.connect(lambda screen: print("new screen", screen))
    w.resize(640, 480)

    app.exec_()
```